# Unable to download PDF created by barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

The issue I'm having may be implementation but I can't find any consistency between PDFs which download correctly and those which return no response data.

I'm using Laravel v5.4.36 and v0.4.0 of Snappy.

I'm using Angular 5 on the front-end. Any requests for PDFs are setting responseType:3 (Blob). The issue isn't how Angular interprets the data, it's that no data is returned when generating some PDFs.

Here are things I've tried to get something to return when using `$pdf->download` or `$pdf->stream`:

- The complexity of the PDF HTML doesn't have any bearing. I can try outputting a simple `<h1>Hello World</h1>` and I get the same result (nothing) that I would from outputting my multi-page HTML
- If I look at the HTML being generated it all looks fine
- If I try to `save()` the PDF it is generated correctly and I can view it without issue
- I've tried using both `PDF::loadView('pdfs.reminder', compact('transactions', 'globalData'))` and `\View::make('pdfs.reminder', compact('transactions', 'globalData'))` to generate the HTML. That doesn't have any effect.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
private function generatePDF($transactions, $globalData)
{
        $html = \View::make('pdfs.reminder', compact('transactions', 'globalData'))->render();
        $pdf = \PDF::loadHTML($html);

        return $pdf->download('reminder.pdf');
}
```

It's also worth noting that some PDFs I've tried to generate have worked. But that is a 1/3 success ratio so far. I'm using the same request format and same methods for all 3. No errors are being thrown.

My suspicion was that perhaps it's the size of the generated PDF which is causing the download to fail. However, I don't imagine that being an issue in a PDF that only contains `<h1>Hello World</h1>`. Are there any limitations in terms of filesize which could cause this behaviour?

Any help with this is appreciated.

## Update

The issue wasn't with Snappy it was that the method which called `generatePDF` didn't return `generatePDF`'s result. Hence why nothing was returned. As that bit of code wasn't in my question it was near impossible for anyone else to help. Thanks to all who tried though.

Comment: What does the `->stream('reminder.pdf')` return?

Comment: you are using the render on blade file which is been passed to PDF as $html .you are suppose to use the render on PDF instance.

Answer (score 2):

E.g

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format('j F, Y');
$application = Application::find($id);
$data = ['date'=>$date,'application'=>$application]; // data to be passes to view file
$pdf =  PDF::loadView('pdfs.reminder', $data)->setPaper('a4');
return $pdf->download('reminder.pdf');
```

Note: Make sure you have use the PDF Class (`use PDF;`) before the class begins.

Comment: @NikolaGavric then you should upvote the answer to show encouragement.

Comment: Agree with @SapneshNaik because it help other's to find the solution quickly thanks.

Comment: Hi @PrashantPrajapati, Thank you for your answer. I've tried your suggestion but it didn't have any impact. Specifically, I stopped using `compact()` and just created an array manually and also used `PDF::loadView()` instead of using `View::make()` (I had already tried switching between the 2 and it didn't make any difference). The class also has `use PDF;` at the top, is that what you meant by your note?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the first line?

```
private function generatePDF($transactions, $globalData){
    $html = \View::make('pdfs.reminder')->render();
    $pdf = \PDF::loadHTML($html);

    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

*pdfs.reminder.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```